# How can you calculate $F(x)=\int_x^{-3} g(t) dt$ if $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)=x^7+x^5+3$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse-function

Consider the function $f(x)=x^7+x^5+3$. Show that the inverse $g(x)$ of $f(x)$ exist and calculate $F'(5)$ if $F(x)=\int_x^{-3} g(t) dt$.

I already showed that $g(x)$ exists y showing that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing (the only critical point was inflection point). However I failed finding $g(x)$ explicitly (and as the problem is formulated I think the idea is to do not find it).

What I tried was, since a function and its inverse, are $(x,f(x))$ and $(g(x),x)$, then they look as reflections over the axis $y=x$. So, notice that $f(x)$ is above the $y=x$ line for $x\geq 3$ then $g(x)$ is under the $y=x$ axis for $x\leq 3$.

So I used the symmetry to stablish that
$$F(x)=\int_x^{-3} g(t) dt = -\int_{3}^{-x} f(t) dt = \int_{-x}^{3} f(t) dt = C - \left(\frac{x^8}{8} + \frac{x^6}{6}-3x \right)$$

And so $F'(x)=-x^{7}-x^{6}+3$, but in $F'(5)$ I get a negative number, and I don't get why this would make sense. Did I messed up a sign somewhere? Is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: The reason you have a negative value for $ \ F'(5) \ $  is  , in a sense, because the integration is being done "right-to-left".  (These "Leibniz rule" problems do not actually call for any integration to be done.  Count on being handed a rather nastier function on the final exam...)

Answer (score 1):

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, you get $F'(x)=-g(x)$  So $F'(5)=-g(5)$

So you are down to solving for x for $5=x^7+x^3+3$,  which by inspection is $x=1$,  thus $F'(5)=-1$.

Your problem was subbing in $f$ for $g$ in the integral before applying the FTC

Comment: wow... now it looks so simple. But also, makes my answer really far off. Why can't I subtitute before using FTC?

Comment: //Umm.  Because  there is no reason to?  The only thing the change in bounds does is make the integral negative.  Why would you think you can swap a function out for its inverse at that step?

Comment: I was thinking on relating both integrals by doing two reflections, over the x axis and the y axis. For the y-reflextion I got the change of limits of integration, hence the change from x to -3 to 3 to -x. And from the x-reflextion I thought that this meant that the integrals are related as one being the negative. I would love to know why thinking that was wrong, maybe for this the solution was simple..but there's always the possibility to find a more difficult fuction.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting your intuition,  but you can pretty well see the two are not related that way by just looking at the graphs of two functions that are inverses and remembering that the definite integral gives you the signed area between the curve and the x-axis.   Try it out with some simple functions and bounds visually